# Git how to pull only some commits

Tags: github, git-commit, pull-request, git-fork

I have some commits that i have made to my own forked repo from the master, now I would like to create a pull request for only some of my commits (some are reverted in my repo). I don't want to clutter up the pull request with my unnecessary commits, what should I do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming "origin" is your remote and you want to create a pull request against "master" branch of "origin".

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b new_branch origin/master
```

Then a bunch of

```
git cherry-pick {commit-id}
```

where `{commit-id}` is specific commit that you want to pick.

When you are done, create a new request from `new_branch`!

Comment: This is the right way to 'pull only some commits'. If you've landed here trying to cherry-pick a commit from master into a branch, make sure your branch is up to date so that it can 'see' the commit.

Answer (score 2):

Better Solution is Create a Local Branch and get code from master branch and make change in your local branch and again push to master and Push to server.  :)

Comment: Ahh, so i just kinda reset everything then make only the necessary ones?

Comment: Yes..., Just you create a local branch(LB), In the beginning LB is empty... and Pull code from master branch(MB) and Clean up your code in LB and Push to MB. may be you will get merge issue in this case one or two file but you can easily solve this problem. later you push to server fro MB. Thanks.